# How do I decode QR Code in Flutter for ZATCA specification

Tags: flutter, decode

i read the qr code for ZATCA QR Code specification in flutter but how can i decode to get the as object or separated string:

```
-Seller’s name
-VAT registration number of the seller
-Time stamp of the Electronic Invoice or Credit/Debit Note (date and time)
-VAT total
-Invoice total
```

i do this code in flutter:

```
var data = base64.decode(string as resultof qr code);
var utf8data = utf8.decode(data);
```

but how to decode utf8data to strings like this :

```
-Seller’s name
-VAT registration number of the seller
-Time stamp of the Electronic Invoice or Credit/Debit Note (date and time)
-VAT total
-Invoice total
```

Answer (score 1):

> For Decode QR Code (Zatca) in PHP

1. Read QR Code - example base64 code
2. Decode the base64 code
3. use preg_replace to remove unicode values from the string

> Sample code

```
$base64 = "AQZSYWZlZXECDTEyMzQ1Njc4OVQxMjUDFDIwMjEtMDctMTJUMTQ6MjU6MDlaBAM3ODYFAjI1";

$decoded = base64_decode($base64);

//print_r($decoded)
//raw data
//\u0001\u0006Rafeeq\u0002\t123456789\u0003\u00142021-07-12T14:25:09Z\u0004\u0003786\u0005\u000225

$result_data = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', ',', $decoded);

$actula_data = explode(',,', $result_data);

print_r($actula_data);
```

Output :

```
["","Rafeeq","123456789T125","2021-07-12T14:25:09Z","786","25"]
```